# rbind dataframes from a list

Tags: r, rbind

One of my functions return a list of dataframes which I need to concatenate into 1 single dataframe. I do this using:

```
 do.call(rbind,list_df)
```

This used to work as expected. But for some strange reason (which is driving me nuts!) it no longer does. Now, instead of combining into a single df, it just retains it as separate lists. When I print the output this is what I get (the list had 2 dataframes with 5 columns each, and the output is retained as such without concatenation)

```
 out_df 
[1,] List,5
[2,] List,5
```

Even when i try this manually without do.call (as shown below) it still gives me the same output, without concatenation:

```
rbind(list_df[[1]],list_df[[2]])
```

I am at a loss trying to figure out what's happening. (Each dataframe in the list has the same attributes - similiar no. of columns and same names, so rbind'ing should ideally work)

Comment: I am guessing that you have a nested list.  Can you show the output of `str(list_df)`

Comment: Yes!! my list_df was getting generated with couple of lapply calls. When I changed one of them to sapply it works. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output of "out_df", it looks like a nested `list`.  We could try

```
out <- do.call(rbind, do.call(c, list_df))
str(out)
# 'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ v1: int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
# $ v2: int  6 7 8 9 10 6 7 8 9 10
# $ v3: int  11 12 13 14 15 11 12 13 14 15
# $ v4: int  16 17 18 19 20 16 17 18 19 20
# $ v5: int  21 22 23 24 25 21 22 23 24 25
```

#### data

```
list_df <- lapply(1:2, function(i) list(data.frame(v1=1:5, 
       v2= 6:10, v3= 11:15, v4 = 16:20, v5= 21:25)))
```

Using the OP's code,

```
do.call(rbind, list_df)
#     [,1]  
#[1,] List,5
#[2,] List,5
```